# Unable to use callback function as an object method

Tags: javascript

object methods are generally declared and used like this

```
points = { 
  first : function(){
    return this.val[0];
  }
};
points.val = [1,2];
points.first(); // returns 1
```

But why am i not allowed to use callbacks instead of a declared method.

```
points.val = [1,2];
points.(function(){
    return this.val[0];
  })();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can by defining a function on points that takes a callback

```
var points = {val:[1,2]};
points.func = function(callback){
    callback.call(this);
}
```

And call it with

```
points.func(function(){
    return this.val;
})
```

You can't use a function as the object key, but you can add a function to the object. You can also define a function outside of the object and use the `.call` or `.apply` methods

```
function val(){
    return this.val;
}

val.call(points);
```

Answer (score 1):

Calling a method on an object consists of two steps:

1. Looking up an object property by key
2. Executing the returned property (which must be a function, or a `TypeError` is raised).

In your first example, your calling code uses the `.` syntax to retrieve the property of `points` with key `first`. It then executes the returned property, which is an anonymous function.

In your second example you are attempting to look up an object with the key:

```
(function(){
  return this.val[0];
})
```

In JavaScript, [Object keys must be valid identifiers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors). [Function expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/function) are not valid identifiers, so the compiler raises a `SyntaxError`.

If you're trying to use a dynamically defined function that uses `this` to refer to `points`, you use `bind`:

```
(function() { return this.val[0] }).bind(points)()
```

Comment: Thanks for answering and i got your point.
so the concept of callbacks cannot be used in object methods? is there another way to code this? my intention is use an undeclared method at that instant.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are trying to do is make a getter/setter for points.

```
points={};

// pass in an array to set points or pass a callback to retrieve them!
points.val = function (points){
//test if points is a callback return points to callback
if (typeof points==="function") return points(this._points); 
// or set the points with the passed in value
this._points=points;
};

//set the points
points.val([1,2])

//get points into callback

points.val(function(e){
    return e[0];
});
```

Comment: no, this is completely different. i want to use callback function as a method where the method is being called so that i dont need to declare it before hand.

Comment: Any chance you can show us an example of the surrounding code so we can understand your problem. In your question you show the first working example and then the second, which does not make sense, what is the problem that you are trying to solve?